# How can I take data from google cloud pubsub to firebase realtime data base

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to take data from google cloud pubsub.The data is generated by an IOT devices.Whenever an IOT device sends data to cloud I need that data to be transferd from pubsub to firebase real time database.I need only the last updated value in the database.How can I do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Cloud Functions. They will do exactly what you need for this.

There's a few pieces you'll need to setup and understand about firebase, so checking out a basic tutorial on that first would be a good plan too.

I did a session recently where we built an application on stage, and the Cloud Function that brought our device telemetry over into Firestore (not Firebase RTD, but same concepts in an updated package):

https://github.com/GabeWeiss/GoogleIoTCoreApp/tree/master/gcf/telemetryToFirestore

That's the code for the Cloud Function itself. To understand the concepts around the pieces you're looking at, check out:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ <-- getting started guides for Firebase (although again, I'd recommend going straight to Firestore)

and

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub <-- tutorial for Pub/Sub Cloud Function tutorials.